# Bitnami Magento 2 Installer - Installed on Azure VM Ubuntu

Tags: installer

I'm a new guy on LAMP stack and trying to install Magento from a Bitnami insatller. (Bitnami Magento 2 installer for Ubuntu 14.04 on Azure VM).

The installation went very well except that I have to use port 8080 to access my online shop from public computer. The URL looks like this:
http://shop.waubulan.com:8080

Please help me on how to change it to a just normal URL http://shop.waubulan.com

Thanks.
Wan

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up Apache to listen on port 80 rather than port 8080.

You should be able to just edit the appropriate config file, look for something along the lines of `Listen 8080` - change that to `Listen 80` and restart Apache, probably with `sudo service apache2 restart`

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291952/how-to-set-a-personalized-port-as-default-in-apache) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case port 80 has been used by other application/interface which I do not know which one. Is this something to do with Varnish configuration?

I further check the config file and Apache is listening to port 8081 .... yes 8081 not 8080. Changing it to port 80 causing an error during Apache restart, because it has been used by other app.

The app that I installed is Magento and was installed using Bitnami Magento stack installer for Ubuntu 14.04.
My virtual machine is running on Azure and dedicated for Magento, and I would not mind to change the machine to only listen on Magento on port 80.
Alternativle making port 8080 as default listening port also OK, so I do not have to key the port number in the public URL.
By the way it also happened in internal URL.

Thanks for your help.